# Loading external page into my web page change the layout

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, zurb-foundation-5

I have a C# MVC web application (application A) where I want to load a web page (P1) from another application. I have got the page P1, details and content, through a REST api call. 
When I load the P1 page into my A1 it messes with my CSS and JS, and overrides the A1 CSS/JS with the one P1 gets from the rest call.

How to make sure P1 does not override the CSS/JS of my page A1?

Answer (score 0):

I do similar approach. I basically take the page of the other app and extract the body element and just embed that. With that approach css of the included app is not loaded

here is example code how I do it:

```
function loadApp(url) {
    // fetch P1 page via jQuery
    $.get(url, function (data) {
        var page = $(data);

        // in the app I have a div with id "frame" where P1 should be loaded into
        $('#frame').html("");
        // in P1 I have a div with id "content" which should be included
        // all CSS and JS are outside
        page.find('#content').appendTo('#frame');

        // rewrite relative urls
        $('#frame').find('img').each(function (i) {
            var src = $(this).attr('src');
            if (!src.toLowerCase().startsWith('http://')) {
                $(this).attr('src', url + '/' + src);
            }
        });
    }, 'html');
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer. It shouldn't even be a comment, since there is no need to confirm a problem.

Comment: Ok. Let me add: you have to use e.g. jQuery to extract the body element from the fetched page and just include that in you app page. As css is usually referred from head element it is so not loaded

Comment: @L.Guthardt, It is an answer. Read it again :)

Comment: That way I have to write my way to display the page? This is not what i want to do.

Comment: I believe you are saying to get the content of P1 and extract only html and discard other things like CSS/JS, if I do so, i loos the look and feel of the other page P1.

Comment: ok - so you are saying that u want to keep the look and feel of the app AND also the look and feel of page P1 (for that area of the screen where u include P1), right?

Comment: Yes, that is what I was looking for.